# Mockito Test not invoking verify() method

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

I'm trying to set up unit tests for an application using Mockito and JUnit. The app in question simply works CRUD methods on a SQL database.  The methods are linked from a DAO layer to the client facing service layer via a manager layer.  This manager layer is where I'm trying to focus my tests.

As of now, I've only made a test for the create method, and it returns the following error:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
dao.createEntry(profile);
-> at com.example.tests.ManagerCRUDTests.testProfileCreate(ManagerCRUDTests.java:60)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

My code is as follows:

```
public class ManagerCRUDTests {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ManagerCRUDTests.class.getName());

    @Mock
    private CrudDAO<Profiles> dao;

    @Mock
    private ProfileManagerImpl manager;

    @Mock
    Profile profile = new Profile();

    public Profile setProfile() {
        profile.setId(1);
        profile.setName("test");
        return profile;
    }

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    }

    @Test
    public void testProfileCreate() throws Exception {
        setProfile();
        logger.info("Testing create for Manager");
        logger.info("Parameters: {}", profile);
        manager.createEntry(profile);
        verify(dao).createEntry(ArgumentMatchers.eq(profile));  //this is where it is failing
        logger.info("Test passed");
    }

}
```

This is my first time really working with unit tests; prior to this, I've only done integration tests.  I'm doing something wrong either in writing my verify method, or in mocking my objects.

Comment: `manager` is a mock, not the real class you want to test, because you've put a `@Mock` annotation on it. So `manager.createEntry(...)` is not going to do anything - specifically, it's not going to call `dao.createEntry(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct your manager to make it the subject under test (not a mock) so in order to correct it i propose :

and no necessary to do initMocks in setup if you use the annotation

```
@Mock
private CrudDAO<Profiles> dao;

@InjectMocks
private ProfileManagerImpl managerUnderTest;

@Mock
Profile profile = new Profile();

public Profile setProfile() {
    profile.setId(1);
    profile.setName("test");
    return profile;
}

@Test
public void testProfileCreate() throws Exception {
    setProfile();
    logger.info("Testing create for Manager");
    logger.info("Parameters: {}", profile);
    managerUnderTest.createEntry(profile);
    verify(dao).createEntry(ArgumentMatchers.eq(profile));  
    logger.info("Test passed");
}
```

Comment: This seems to work.  One thing though - if I get rid of initMocks(this), code throws a NullPointerException.  If I keep it in, the test passes.

Answer (score 0):

`manager` is defined as a `@Mock`. So it will not use any of its dependencies.
A common aproach would be do have `manager` as `@InjectMocks`. That will create an instance with all dependencies replaced/set as `@Mock`